# I want to slice out substrings using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
str_ = "8983605653Sudanshu452365423256Shinde"
print(re.findall(r"\d{10}\B|[A-Za-z]{8}|\d{12}|[A-Za-z]{6}",str_))
```

current output

```
['8983605653', 'Sudanshu', '4523654232', 'Shinde']
```

Desired output

```
['8983605653', 'Sudanshu', '452365423256', 'Shinde']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an alternation `|` you can use the matches with capture groups and then print the group values.

```
import re

str_ = "8983605653Sudanshu452365423256Shinde"
m = re.match(r"(\d{10})([A-Za-z]{8})(\d{12})([A-Za-z]{6})",str_)
if m:
    print(list(m.groups()))
```

Output

```
['8983605653', 'Sudanshu', '452365423256', 'Shinde']
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/RiJIUo).

Answer (score 1):

A regex find all on `\d+|\D+` should work here:

```py
str_ = "8983605653Sudanshu452365423256Shinde"
matches = re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', str_)
print(matches)  # ['8983605653', 'Sudanshu', '452365423256', 'Shinde']
```

The pattern used here alternatively finds all digit substrings, or all non digit substrings.